# Phaser: InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, phaser, error-management

I am using the [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) framework for game development, but while working on it I face a bug which is annoying, I have the following message:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

[image]

The consequence is that because of it I now cannot move my hero, I need to first click once on the phaser window and then it worked, so I tried to debug it, and even by using the default phaser demo the same error message appear and cause the same but, so i concluded that my code is not the problem.

Do you please have any idea? Is there a way to know how to fix it ? Otherwise  how can have more details about it in the console?

***Note: if you wanna download the official starting tutorial to reproduce the error:***

1. Download `.zip`: [here](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/phaser3-tutorial-src.zip)
2. Beginner Tutorial: [here](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/index)

Comment: I get the same error but only in FF. In Chrome I don't get it. Haven't tested other browsers either.